# Excel VBA Error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error with double quotes in my formula

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to add a formula using VBA to a cell in Excel, the (simplified) code is as

```
    Dim destRow as integer
    destRow = 107
    Cells(destRow, 19) = "=IF(L" & destRow & "="""";"""";""UNB"")"
```

`I've also tried the following (in place of the last line):

```
    Cells(destRow, 19) = "=IF(L" & destRow & "=" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ";" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ";" & chr(34) & "UNB" & chr(34) & ")"
```

In the immediate window, both produce the correct output:

```
    =IF(L107="";"";"UNB")
```

...however, I get error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the last line when I run my code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try this: `Cells(destRow, 1) = "=IF(L" & destRow & "="""","""",""UNB"")"`

Comment: Spot on Alex!  Thanks for that!
Whats the deal with ; and , in excel?  On my machine, when the formula is in the cell, Excel requires a ; otherwise it whinges, but when using VBA it whinges if I don't use a ,
Is that something like the date format (mm/dd/yyyy) thing in VBA in that it expects a certain format?  Then why would the app behave differently in the regular interface?
Thanks again!

Comment: That's odd - in my experience i've always used commas.  It seems to be a regional thing http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/385317-semicolon-comma-regional.html  I guess to do with the fact that in some regions ten thousand is written 10.000,00

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the semicolons ";" in the IF formula for commas ",". They will appear as semicolons depending on your excel configuration when the formula is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably just need to refer to the relevant worksheet.

Your code would work if it was in the code for a sheet rather than in a module.

So

```
Sheet1.Cells(destRow, 19) = "=IF(L" & destRow & "=" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ";" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ";" & chr(34) & "UNB" & chr(34) & ")"
```

Obviously substitute for the desired sheet if it's not Sheet1

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it's not that on my system.  Did you try the code on your system?  I've tried a fully qualified cell reference and it's exactly the same.  The code is in a sheet module.

I have some lines prior to that one in my code that use the same type of reference, but without double quotes, and they fire off fine.  Unfortunately the formula I'm inserting requires double quotes.